# Code to read Word docs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-word, automation, ms-office

I need a script (or other code, C#, etc.) that will fetch every paragraph/sentence containing a particular word in a set of Word 2007 documents and move them to a new Word document, recording the filename of the original (source) document they were extracted from.

Comment: Are the documents in `docx` format?

Comment: You can use Office automation or Aspose.Words.

Comment: Yes, it's a docx (2007) document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a document indexer, such as [dtSearch](http://www.dtsearch.com/PLF_engine_2.html) to index your documents (word, pdf, etc), and then tap into their API to do your unique searches that way. From what it sounds that might be the fastest way to accomplish this. Granted indexers like dtSearch cost money (not a whole lot), but sometimes it may be worth the cost compared to the hours you will spend trying to write your own code to do the same thing.

Some articles that I have found that might lead you in the right direction if you don't want to use an indexer are:

http://omegacoder.com/?p=555

and

http://weblogs.asp.net/guystarbuck/archive/2008/05/13/automated-search-and-replace-in-multiple-word-2007-documents-with-c.aspx

**Edit**
To find a sentence that contains a specific word, you can try this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546163.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Jason. The trickiest part is grabbing the sentence/paragraph that contains the word. How do you do that programmatically?

Comment: Hey Alex, see if this link helps you with that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546163.aspx

Comment: Just what I needed! Thanks, Jason :)

Answer (score 1):

This might give you a start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff834910.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Office Interop is an option but beware: it is **not supported** by MS in server-like scenarios (like ASP.NET or Windows Service or similar) - see http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2 !

You will need to use some library to achieve what you want:

- [MS provides the OpenXML SDK V 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854%28office.14%29.aspx) (free)
- [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) (commercial)